# Salesforce Dev Release Exam - Spring 15

Tags: certification

Today I registered and attempted the dev release exam for Spring 15.

I did refer materials online (as it is unproctored) but when I submitted the exam I was told the result is a "Fail".

The questions were simple and I am lil confused as to how I could have failed but thats an altogether separate topic..not for SFSE discussion

My Q is :

Should I **answer correctly all** of the questions in the developer release exam or is there any passing percentage ?

Comment: I have been on Google a few times because I felt like there was a scoring error with this exam. I took the Admin exam and passed a few weeks ago. A few minutes later I took the Developer Exam and failed. I think there were 5 questions and 4 were same as Admin. I took it again and also failed. I only get 1 more time but don't understand the issue. I've been certified for 3 years so taken dozens of these.

Answer (score 4):

I think it's usually around 70-80%. Given the fact there are only a few questions, you're allowed to fail only 1 of the 5-6 questions, speaking from my personal experience over the past few years.